# CSS3 preventing AJAX click event

Tags: css, ajax

I am using a bit of CSS3 gradient to paint the background of a link, to make it look like a button. I'm also adding text shadow when the link is active. Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="inner-page-sidebar">

    <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">               
        <aside id="nav_menu-4" class="sidebar-four-widget widget widget_nav_menu"><h3 class="widget-title">About</h3><div class="menu-sidebar-4-menu-1-about-container"><ul id="menu-sidebar-4-menu-1-about" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-1223" class="ajax-link menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1223"><a href="http://hiddenwebdomain.com/about/the-company/">The Company</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1134" class="ajax-link menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor menu-item-1134"><a href="http://hiddenwebdomain.com/about/corporate-governance/">Corporate Governance</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1224" class="ajax-link menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1224"><a href="http://hiddenwebdomain.com/about/employment/">Employment</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1111" class="ajax-link menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1111"><a href="http://hiddenwebdomain.com/about/customer-service/">Customer Service</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1113" class="ajax-link menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1113"><a href="http://hiddenwebdomain.com/about/faqs/">FAQs</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1114" class="ajax-link menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1114"><a href="http://hiddenwebdomain.com/about/contact-us-2/">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul></div></aside>

<aside id="nav_menu-5" class="sidebar-four-widget widget widget_nav_menu"><h3 class="widget-title">Corporate Information</h3><div class="menu-sidebar-4-menu-2-corporate-info-container"><ul id="menu-sidebar-4-menu-2-corporate-info" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-1115" class="ajax-link menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1115"><a href="http://hiddenwebdomain.com/about/corporate-governance/board-of-directors/">Board of Directors</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1116" class="ajax-link menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1116"><a href="http://hiddenwebdomain.com/about/corporate-governance/management-team/">Management Team</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1117" class="ajax-link menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-645 current_page_item menu-item-1117"><a href="http://hiddenwebdomain.com/about/corporate-governance/code-of-ethics/">Code of Ethics</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1118" class="ajax-link menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1118"><a href="http://hiddenwebdomain.com/about/corporate-governance/audit-committee-charter/">Audit Committee Charter</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1119" class="ajax-link menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1119"><a href="http://hiddenwebdomain.com/about/corporate-governance/compensation-committee-charter/">Compensation Committee</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1120" class="ajax-link menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1120"><a href="http://hiddenwebdomain.com/about/corporate-governance/nominating-and-corporate-governance-committee-charter/">Nominating And Governance</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1121" class="ajax-link menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1121"><a href="http://hiddenwebdomain.com/about/corporate-governance/contact-non-management-directors/">Contact Directors</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1122" class="ajax-link menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1122"><a href="http://hiddenwebdomain.com/about/corporate-governance/contact-audit-committee/">Contact Audit Committee</a></li>
    </ul></div></aside>
```

```
    </div> <!-- END INNER-PAGE-SIDEBAR -->
```

And here's CSS:

```
.dealer-selector-button-gradient,
.widget_nav_menu ul li a {
    color: #505050;
    border: solid 1px #c6c6c6;  
    background: #f1f1f1;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#f1f1f1)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f1f1f1); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f1f1f1); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f1f1f1); /* IE10 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f1f1f1); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f1f1f1); /* W3C */
}

.dealer-selector-button-gradient:hover,
.widget_nav_menu ul li a:hover {
    background: #e4e4e4;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#e0e0e0)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e0e0e0); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e0e0e0); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e0e0e0); /* IE10 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e0e0e0); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e0e0e0); /* W3C */
}

.dealer-selector-button-gradient:active,
.widget_nav_menu ul li a:active {
    color: #505050;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    background: #f5f5f5;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f1f1f1), to(#ffffff)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f1f1f1, #ffffff); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f1f1f1, #ffffff); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f1f1f1, #ffffff); /* IE10 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f1f1f1, #ffffff); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #f1f1f1, #ffffff); /* W3C */
}
```

There must be something I'm doing wrong here, because when I load that page with AJAX, sometimes clicking on any of the links formatted like that fails to generate the click event.

I tested AJAX code through and through, and there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with it.

Then I removed the CSS, and sure enough, the click event occurs every time.

**UPDATE:** I actually disabled JavaScript in a browser and tested the page without JavaScript, and for some reason, not every time, but once in about fifty or so clicks, a click on the formatted link doesn't work.

**UPDATE 2**: To make things even stranger, if a link fails to open the new page (even with JS disabled in a browser), I can click on it a hundred times, and it won't work – but moving a cursor slightly, by a pixel, and clicking again – enables the link.

What could cause that issue? Is there a way to recreate the same CSS differently, to make sure that CSS doesn't interfere with the click event?

Comment: Can you setup new fiddle? I think there's no logical reason why this snippet wont work.

Comment: Are you saying therefore, that it definitely works without the CSS? Are you sure there are no other errors (eg HTML/JS errors) in the page? I can't imagine anything in CSS would make a click not work. Use "inspect element" or Firebug etc and make sure you don't have a transparent CSS element floating over the top of the item you want to click on.

Comment: Are you sure the relevant part of the CSS is posted? More likely than colors on the links, there is a positioning of something else causing the issue, like maybe a transparent overlay that you're clicking on instead of the link. Do you have a link to the site with the issue? Or even better, a demo like @KristianVitozev suggests?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, @NickG – I just removed the CSS, the links work all the time. Put CSS back – link fails. Common sense says, it's gotta be CSS, even though I have no idea why wouldn't it work? Trying your Firebug suggestion now.

Comment: Removing that very CSS solves the issue, @xec.

Comment: Thanks, @Kristian – trying to create a fiddle that would have the same issue...

Comment: @KeithRules, I think if you simply add few links and style them with CSS you will not see the same problem. Maybe it's related to other markup code in your page. Can you show us more code? :)

Comment: Adding it to the body of the question, thank you, @KristianVitozev

Comment: Added, @KristianVitozev – would be grateful if you could take a look.

Comment: Created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/yCcR4/ ...but it seems to work fine for me. I think the error must be in some HTML, CSS or JS you've not posted.

Comment: These damn links fail even when I disable JS, @Nick. Let me see at all the other code associated with them. Thank you!

Comment: If all else fails, use the "divide and conquer" strategy. Remove half the CSS, test, then remove the other half and test, to see which half contains the problem.  Then do the same again with the suspect half until you narrow it enough to reveal the problem line.

Answer (score 1):

Found my own answer, thanks to extended discussion in comments. Writing this answer in case anyone experiences similar issue and arrives to this page.

The culprit was a small rule that was actually hidden elsewhere in the stylesheet – but applied to the same element, just as was suggested.

That rule added `margin-top: 1px;` to the buttons in active state. For some reason, even though a button generated `mousedown` event, it failed to `click` event.

Removing that rule solved the problem.